# How to write a SharePoint WebPart with multiple Controls

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have a stock chart and some other controls in my SharePoint WebPart...

I am unable to call all the controls in the WebPart, only one control displayed in the WebPart or the ASP server controls rendered as a object. For example Label control is rendered as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label but the actual Label control is not displaying.

Please give me the approach to overcome this problem.

Thanks,
Bhanu

Comment: Are you able to post some source code tohelp us identify your issue? My bet is that you've not added the Label control to the this.Controls collection.

Answer (score 1):

Within your CreateChildControls(), it should have something like this:

```
Label x = new Label();
x.Text = "hello world";
this.Controls.Add(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

What Andrew said, an in addition you could also add them to another panel to gain some div layout control:

```
Label x = new Label();
x.Text = "hello world";

Label y = new Label();
y.Text = "hello world2";

Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.CssClass = "my-panel";
panel.Controls.Add(x);
panel.Controls.Add(y);

this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

This is all going from memory, so you might need to tweak a couple things.